# Will it ruin my chances to be PR in Canada if I marry my foreign boyfriend?

Tags: canada, residency

I am an international student and graduating next year June and I was wondering if marrying my boyfriend (who will be on a tourist visa) in Canada after my graduation will affect my chance to be Permanent Resident in Canada? From what I know, after living in Canada for 3 years straight, I am eligible to apply for a PR. Would marrying my non-canadian boyfriend in any way affect my chances of attaining PR?

Comment: Your chances won't change but your boyfriend needs to prepare very, very well for the border crossing. He shouldn't lie but he shouldn't offer even a hint of marriage unless specifically asked because then he very likely will be denied entry for fear of overstay. Like, say girlfriend and not fiancé and so on.

Comment: I'm not seeing that you will immediately be able to apply for PR unless you'll already qualify for express entry which requires work experience. Can you point me to a page that you're relying on?

Comment: @mkennedy: I think it's not completely clear whether the OP currently lives in Canada or not. It could be read either way, but I suspect she has been attending school in Canada for at least 3 years.

Comment: I am currently living in Canada and I am graduating next year therefore my boyfriend and I plan to get married in Canada. I just wonder if this will ruin my chances of attaining a PR and if not can i sponsor him after i become a PR?

Answer (score 3):

If you are married, you have to provide your spouse detail information as the co-applicant(extra fees and background checks like the criminal records).  In some cases, your spouse can add extra points for your PR application(e.g language exam score). You should consider all scenarios since that your marital status will definitely affect your eligibility in both positive or negative ways.  In general, that makes things a little more complex. Please consult the CIC official information as your guidance.

REF: [CIC  Entry criteria and the Comprehensive Ranking System](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/express-entry/criteria-crs.asp) 
  Date Modified:  2017-07-14